# cant pull up results through daterange and txtbox at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

now the problem with this code is that its pulling up results by text(cityname) but not through date range

UI is fine, as it was working earlier when i had 2 different stored procedure for these 2 functions

```
 @start_date DateTime
,@end_date DateTime = null
,@city nvarchar(20) = null
AS
BEGIN
declare @startdate datetime 
set @start_date = '2999-01-01'

if (@start_date = DAY(getdate()) and @end_date is null and @city is null)
   begin
      select jp.id, city.name[City]
             , row_number() over (order by city.name) [sr_no]
             , count(jp.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_posts 
             , COUNT(od.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_employers
             ,CONVERT(varchar(12), jp.posting_date, 103) [date_created]
        from rs_job_posting jp
             inner join rs_job_posting_location jpl on jpl.id = jp.id
             inner join rs_cor_city city on city.id = jpl.city_fk
             inner join rs_organization_detail od on od.id = jp.id
       where DAY(posting_date) = @start_date
        order by no_of_posts Desc 
   END

if @start_date = DAY(getdate()) and @end_date = DAY(getdate()) and @city is null
  begin
   select jp.id, city.name[City]
        , row_number() over (order by city.name) [sr_no]
        , count(jp.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_posts 
        , COUNT(od.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_employers
        ,CONVERT(varchar(12), jp.posting_date, 103) [date_created]
     from rs_job_posting jp
        inner join rs_job_posting_location jpl on jpl.id = jp.id
        inner join rs_cor_city city on city.id = jpl.city_fk
        inner join rs_organization_detail od on od.id = jp.id
    where DAY(posting_date) = @start_date and DAY(end_date) = @end_date
    order by no_of_posts Desc 
  end

else if @city is not null
  begin
    select jp.id, city.name[City]
        , row_number() over (order by city.name) [sr_no]
        , count(jp.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_posts 
        , COUNT(od.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_employers
        ,CONVERT(varchar(12), jp.posting_date, 103) [date_created]
     from rs_job_posting jp
        inner join rs_job_posting_location jpl on jpl.id = jp.id
        inner join rs_cor_city city on city.id = jpl.city_fk
        inner join rs_organization_detail od on od.id = jp.id
    where DAY(posting_date) = @start_date 
      and DAY(end_date) = @end_date 
      and city.name like '%' + @city + '%'
    order by no_of_posts Desc 
  end

 select jp.id, city.name[City]
        , row_number() over (order by city.name) [sr_no]
        , count(jp.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_posts 
        , COUNT(od.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_employers
        ,CONVERT(varchar(12), jp.posting_date, 103) [date_created]
   from rs_job_posting jp
        inner join rs_job_posting_location jpl on jpl.id = jp.id
        inner join rs_cor_city city on city.id = jpl.city_fk
        inner join rs_organization_detail od on od.id = jp.id
  where DAY(posting_date) = @start_date 
    and DAY(end_date) = @end_date 
     or city.name like '%' + @city + '%'
  order by no_of_posts Desc
```

Comment: You should consider to put `()` on this: and DAY(end_date) = @end_date or city.name like '%' + @city + '%' as it has an OR statement. On the last query. It should be: `and (DAY(end_date) = @end_date or city.name like '%' + @city + '%')`

Comment: its still not working, its seems like its skipping start_date and end_date parameters and simply taking @city one.

Answer (score 0):

Inferring the logic in the query form your question, given below is a simplified one without the if else construct. Your might not have worked since the you did not convert the parameters to day() (`@start_date = DAY(getdate())`)

```
select jp.id, city.name[City]
                , row_number() over (order by city.name) [sr_no]
                , count(jp.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_posts 
                , COUNT(od.id) over (partition by name) as no_of_employers
                ,CONVERT(varchar(12), jp.posting_date, 103) [date_created]
           from rs_job_posting jp
                inner join rs_job_posting_location jpl on jpl.id = jp.id
                inner join rs_cor_city city on city.id = jpl.city_fk
                inner join rs_organization_detail od on od.id = jp.id
          where (DAY(posting_date) = day(@start_date ) 
                    and (DAY(@startDate) = day(GETDATE()) or @city is not null)
                )
            and (
                    (DAY(end_date) = day(@end_date)and (DAY(@startDate) = day(GETDATE()) or @city is not null))
                     or @end_date is null
                )
            and (city.name like '%' + @city + '%' or @city is null)
          order by no_of_posts Desc
```

**Note**: I suggest you to consider the month and year part too, instead of just comparing by day part only.